# How to make the "Trumpet" lead in this track?

Tags: sound-design, design, replication

I am really wondering how the artist of this track made such a clear "trumpet" drop.

1.15 @

Could someone please explain how this could be reproduced with Sylenth1, Spire or any other Synthesizer.

Comment: it's not a trumpet, it's a bad sax sample.

Comment: arigatou gozaimasu, do you have a good sample of it?

Comment: Google 'free samples saxophone' It's possibly a tenor sax, if you need to choose. I'm afraid I don't have anything that rough ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a sample, it will be difficult to re-create with any synthesizer. To me it sounds like a baritone saxophone playing high notes. You can look for free sax samples and load them into a sampling program, or find a sax VST. As for how to make it "clear", start with a good sample and apply the common production techniques (EQ, slight sidechain compression, etc).